# What is meant by the revision that tortoise svn shows at update? This revsion number is different from the head revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise GUI as well as command line. Whenever I update, in the logs/console, at the end it say's 'Completed | At revision 7221'

But when I go to repository I see a different revision number say 7137 sitting at the top of this branch or trunk.

Is my understanding is wrong that last commit on branch/trunk is the 'HEAD' (7137)? 
In this example 7221 doesn't exit anywhere in revision graph. What it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say for example you, Saurabh, are working on a branch `MyBranch` and the rest of your team is working off of `trunk`. Let's pretend this is your structure:

```
root
--trunk
--tags
--branches
----MyBranch
```

The last commit you made to `MyBranch` was revision 7137. However, the revision numbers you see don't apply to just your branch. They apply to the *entire* repository. So your team has made commits up to revision 7221 in that **repository** (includes branches/tag/trunk/etc). So whenever you run a generic `svn update`, subversion updates to the HEAD revision of that *repository*, which is 7221. However, your revision log will only state 7137 because that's just the last commit for that particular branch.

If you did an `svn log` on the `root` level of the repository, you would see the list of commits to the other directories.

Comment: Thanks!! I had the wrong perceptions!!, I did run 'svn log htps://svnrepo.mycompany.com/svn/mysvndevrepo/' and I saw the same number as I get on update. Well I wish svn update could be giving me the last commit revision number, that will be helpful in my build-release automation project, where I can tell team that this particular svn revision is going for release.

Comment: @SaurabhTripathi Not a problem, here to help. However, you can still get that revision number for that branch by simply running `svn info path/to/checkout` and parsing the field that says `Last Changed Rev: 7137`.